# SiPM transimpedance amplifier design

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, transimpedance-amplifier

I'm designing a transimpedance amplifier for a SiPM (Silicon Photo Multiplier Array Broadcom [AFBR-S4N44C013](https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/AFBR-S4N44C013-DS)) sensor. Basically I want the output to be 3.2 V max. so I can input it into an Arduino, with output voltages dropping as the brightness drops.

I'm using a 36 V bias voltage from a custom 3.2 V to 36 V booster.

However, the issue I'm having is that the output of the op-amp won't change; it's stuck at 3.2 V no matter the SiPM brightness. If I remove C4 and R4 the SiPM begins to overheat. Also, since the SiPM is operating in reverse bias I believe that the SiPM's C (cathode) should be connected to the 36+ input, so please disregard that error in the schematic. The op-amp is a TLV9101|DBVR.

I've attached the TIA schematic (buffer part of circuit is currently not being used/connected) and the voltage booster schematic.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: tia schematic]

[image]

Comment: Check the opamp's inputs. The non-inverting seems to be connected to a voltage of (31.6/32.6)*3.3V and the inverting input is DC coupled to the output. That will copy the non-inverting input's voltage to the output: 3.2 V.

Comment: Oh true, how would I fix it?

Comment: This circuit has many issues. What do you want to acheive with it? This kind of sensor creates very short pulses for single photons. They are probably invisible to an Arduino.

Comment: I want to detect low levels of light from organic substances